# Alternative to Select Into

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using SQLite in a Delphi XE7 application and need to make a copy of any number of a possible 106 columns from one table into another table that needs to be created dynaically using the same types. If "Select Into" worked with SQLite, the SQL would look something like:

```
  SELECT 
    "RecNum", 
    "TK Number", 
    "Type", 
    "Disc.",
    "Project Description",
    "Date Added"
  INTO
    "CurrentLimited"
  FROM
    "Current"
```

If those were the selected fields. The target and source tablenames will be static. The query is attached to a TQuery, so if there is a way to save the results of the TQuery as a table in the same database (I don't think SaveToFile offers that) then that would work too.

Comment: `insert into CurrentLimited (columns...) select columns... from Current`?

Comment: Except that the columns are selected by the user and could be any number of a possible 106 columns. Insert Into uses a pre-existing table.

Comment: Do you have any more unspecified requirements that you haven't included? It's pretty time-wasting to offer suggestions only to have you tell us "yeah, except I have some reason it won't work". Please [edit] your question and explain what you're actually trying to do more specifically so we don't waste our (and your) time playing 20 questions to try to figure it out.

Comment: Use insert into and generate your SQL at runtime

Comment: I don't use spaces when I design databases. This is a pre-existing imported database from a client.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE
  CurrentLimited 
AS
  SELECT
    "RecNum",
    "TK Number",
    "Type",
    "Disc.",
    "Project Description",
    "Date Added"  
  FROM 
    "Current"
```